# How to build react native for test flight

Tags: react-native

I have uploaded a build of my react native app to testflight. Once I install the app via testflight on a device the app starts up and then I just get a white screen, like the JS is not included or something.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I usually added the main.jsbundle file through the "add files to project..." dialogue. Turns out you have to copy that file to the iOS sub directory in the project.